# Reading .qlr (QGIS file definition layer) in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: qgis, arcgis-pro, layer-file, compatibility, qlr

Is there any way to open a .qlr file (layer definition in QGIS) in ArcGIS Pro?

If not, is there any workaround to export my QGIS symbology to Pro?

Comment: Workaround: Note your symbologies and recreate them in Arc.

Comment: The short answer is no and the best workaround is probably to recreate them in ArcGIS as Erik suggested.   If this is going to be ongoing, your best bet would be to create the symbology in ArcGIS and then use the QGIS slyr plugin or ArcGIS Online sld converter to get them into QGIS.  I suppose you might be able to take advantage of ArcGIS's Match Layer Symbology to a Style by saving your QGIS symbols with a name to match the layer.  See https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/match-layer-symbology-to-a-style.htm.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no proper workaround to do this and recreating the symbology is simply the best option.